# Selenium Python, How can I download a PDF to a specific location without having the "url"

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I've been writing a code with python using Selenium that should access a webpage and download a pdf. But, when the driver clicks on the button it generates a new tab with the pdf, and I can't use that URL to download the PDF.
Can anyone help me, please?

(example: if I ask my driver to "get" the PDF "URL", the driver opens the page I was before, the one it had the button that opens the PDF Chrome previewer)

If the problem seems understandable please inform me so I can try to explain it better.

Comment: Configure it in your settings: https://www.howtogeek.com/721441/how-to-download-pdfs-instead-of-previewing-them-in-chrome-firefox-and-edge/#:~:text=Click%20%E2%80%9CSite%20Settings%E2%80%9D%20on%20the,opening%20them%20in%20Chrome%E2%80%9D%20option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the default configuration of chrome is to disable the download for security reasons. You may change this in the options. I am attaching a working example based on [Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/) which has safe pdf downloads:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Downloads"), #Set directory to save your downloaded files.
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #Downloads the file without confirmation.
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #Disable PDF opening.
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Downloads","chromedriver"),options=options) #Replace with correct path to your chromedriver executable.


driver.get("https://arxiv.org/list/hep-lat/1902") #Base url


driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/dl/dt[1]/span/a[2]")[0].click() #Clicks the link that would normally open the PDF, now download. Change to fit your needs
```